# Error in colMeans(x, na.rm = TRUE) : 'x' debe ser numérico en RStudio Clustering

Tags: rstudio

Tengo una base de datos que se parece a la de USArrests (la primera fila y columna son caracteres)
[image: Nombres de las columnas y nombres de las filas]

Pero al querer hacer algunos comandos de Clustering, me manda, lo siguiente (ejemplo)

> datos <- scale(Clusters_Lemna)

Error in colMeans(x, na.rm = TRUE) : 'x' debe ser numérico

en otra línea me sale

> mat_distp <- get_dist(x = datos, method = "pearson")

Error in stats::cor(t(x), method = method) : 'x' must be numeric

¿como puedo hacer para que no me considere la primera columna de caracteres, pero si aparezcan si quiero usar comandos como "fviz_cluster"?

Gracias de antemano